# Jenkins: service account got locked

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins master is running under an AD account, and some slaves on another server are also running under this account. The password got changed two days ago. So we changed the logon password in master and restart the service, but the account got locked in the last two days. How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the slaves run on Windows then:

- Is the process really running under the user you think it should?  (task man and find java or run services.msc and check the jenkins service runas  -- on lin it would be (ps -ef|grep java or -i jenkins)
- Is there a log in the jenkins directory on the slave
- Do you see entries in the system logs (LogViewer)?
- Have you tried rebooting the slave system?  It shouldn't have any impact, but it is easily tried.

Comment: Feb 24, 2016 10:04:58 AM hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSite createSession
INFO: creating Jira Session: http://invjira/
Feb 24, 2016 10:05:11 AM hudson.plugins.jira.JiraRestService getUser
WARNING: jira rest client get user error. cause: RestClientException{statusCode=Optional.of(401), errorCollections=[]}
Feb 24, 2016 10:05:11 AM com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService executeSOAPRequestInternal
INFO: SOAP method='ReadIdentities', status=200, content-length=2006, server-wait=9 ms, parse=1 ms, total=10 ms, throughput=200600 B/s, gzip

Comment: I found the above in the jenkins.error.log, what does it doing?

Comment: Looks like it is talking to jira.  I suspect you've got jenkins setup up update jira upon build completion.   In that case ,it extracts ticket IDs from commit comments and then uses them plus auth info to connect and add a comment.    Perhaps that auth info is bad which could lock the account.  If Jira is AD then jenkins is OK on AD but it's failed attempt to auth to jira lock the account creating the failure.